# How to let eclipse break on a stack overflow?

Tags: java, eclipse, stack-overflow

I get a stacktrace that indicates a stack overflow caused by a non-terminating program. However I don't know how to let the eclipse debugger break when this occurs.

I'd rather not post the stacktrace but it starts with:

```
JVM Error!
    at ___
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.HandlerWrapper.handle(HandlerWrapper.java:113)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.Server.handle(Server.java:334)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.HttpConnection.handleRequest(HttpConnection.java:559)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.HttpConnection$RequestHandler.headerComplete(HttpConnection.java:992)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.http.HttpParser.parseNext(HttpParser.java:550)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.http.HttpParser.parseAvailable(HttpParser.java:203)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.HttpConnection.handle(HttpConnection.java:406)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.io.nio.SelectChannelEndPoint.run(SelectChannelEndPoint.java:462)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.QueuedThreadPool$2.run(QueuedThreadPool.java:436)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
Caused by:
null
    at ___
```

Followed by a very long repeating sequence of function calls.

Thanks for any help

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can let the debugger break on Exceptions. In your case, try breaking on the `java.lang.StackOverflowError`

Check this out:
http://help.eclipse.org/helios/index.jsp?topic=/org.eclipse.jdt.doc.user/reference/views/breakpoints/ref-breakpoints_view.htm

Comment: I don't see any reference to StackOverflowError in the stack trace, but I'll try. I can't break on all Exceptions in general cause that would break on other valid exceptions.

Answer (score 0):

You can set the debugger to break on edit -

In the Debug perspective .

Select the Add Exception Breakpoint command to add a Java exception breakpoint.

In the resulting dialog:

- In the Choose an Exception field, type a string that is contained in the name of the exception you want to add. You can use wildcards as needed ("* " for any string and "? " for any character).
- In the Matching types list , select the exception you want to add.
  Select Caught and Uncaught as needed to indicate on which exception type you want to suspend the program.

Answer (score -3):

Increase your memerory size. When you running program pass this into VM Args.

Xms512m -Xmx512m -XX:PermSize=256m -XX:MaxPermSize=256m

Comment: That is not what the asker needed. He wants his IDE to break when an exception happens.

Comment: -1 I second that. If you have stack overflows, usually memory is not the issue, but you have a recursive bug. But you can paste your answer to this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5064124/how-to-avoid-out-of-memory-in-string-builder-or-string-in-java :-)

Comment: increasing memory size won't work anyway if he's got an infinite recursion or something similar (like a circular chain of method calls) going on (which is probably what's happening). It'll just delay the inevitable.